# How to Make Array of Float Data Type in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, nsarray

I want to make array of float type. 
Anybody can help me?

```
NSArray *arrOfFloat = [[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[12.2, 23.44], nil]];
```

But i want to make array dynamically.

Comment: Look into `NSMutableArray` as `NSArray` is not mutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`But i want to make array dynamically.`

This means you'll have to use an [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[array addObject:@1.1];
[array addObject:@2.2];
...
```

You also can't add primitives to an array. You'll need to add objects. Notice the `@` I added before the numbers. This creates [number literals.](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#nsnumber-literals)

If you have the floats you want to add as variables, you can [auto boxing](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#boxed-expressions) like this:

```
[array addObject:@(myFloatVariable)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [NSMutableArray class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of a NSArray (this is a subclass of it), this way, within your code, you will be able to call :

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [NSMutableArray new];
[yourArray addObject:@(1.0f)];
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSArray`can only store objects, so in your case you would have to store your `float` as `NSNumber`. If you want to store objects dynamically, thus adding or removing them to an `NSArray` you have to use the mutable object type called `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wrap your `float`'s in an `NSNumber`:

```
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:12.2];
```

If you're dynamically adding elements to an array, you need to use `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:12.2]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **NSMutableArray** for example named arrOfFloat and add this :

```
[arrOfFloat addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.5]];
[arrOfFloat addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:23.44]];
```

Hope, It will may helpful to you.